# Ajax error after update apache cordova to 5

Tags: android, cordova

I have just updated my app to version 5 of apache cordova, but now I keep receiving: **404 (Not Found)** on my AJAX requests, I also checked config.xml and access origin parameter is *.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeking a solution to the problem, I found a answer in documentation, I just install the new cordova-plugin-whitelist and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

After update to the Cordova 5 if you develop on Android platform version 4.0 you should add `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin. 
Now by default all network requests is blocked. You could use CSP(Content Security Policy) to specify which resources allowed to access by webpage inside Cordova App.